# list doesn't scroll on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two identical lists in my html code and I want that if I select an element in one list then the other list should automatically scroll to that element in it, for that I have written the code below but this is not working, means when I click any element in list-1 nothing is going to happen in list-2. I am using chrome browser on windows 8.1. please solve the problem.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#l1 li').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).html();
                $('#l2 li').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('color','black');
                    if($(this).html() == val) {
                        $(this).css('color','red');
                        $('#l2').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
                        });
                    }     
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="l1" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px">
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="l2" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:350px">
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a jsfiddle and it works find "https://jsfiddle.net/n8403xft/" the only thing in your code is you are missing the

```
$(function()
{
    // Insert code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your are executing code before DOM is built.

You have to use `$(document).ready(function(){})`, that means your code will be executed when DOM is loaded.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#l1 li').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).html();
                $('#l2 li').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('color','black');
                    if($(this).html() == val) {
                        $(this).css('color','red');
                        $('#l2').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
                        });
                    }     
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="l1" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px">
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="l2" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:350px">
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not dependent to any browser or any os, Just Replace your script tag code with this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#l1 li').click(function () {
        var val = $(this).html();
        $('#l2 li').each(function () {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
            if ($(this).html() == val) {
                $(this).css('color', 'red');
                $('#l2').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the click event before elements are loaded.  Put your `js` in the last of `body` tag like following. Hope this will help you.

```html
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="l1" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:150px">
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="l2" style="height:100px; width:70px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; position:absolute; top:50px; left:350px">
            <li>purple</li>
            <li>pink</li>
            <li>grey</li>
            <li>brown</li>
            <li>red</li>
            <li>green</li>
            <li>blue</li>
            <li>yellow</li>
            <li>black</li>
            <li>orange</li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $('#l1 li').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).html();
                $('#l2 li').each(function() {
                    $(this).css('color','black');
                    if($(this).html() == val) {
                        $(this).css('color','red');
                        $('#l2').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#l2').offset().top + $('#l2').scrollTop()
                        });
                    }     
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```